# netlink ipset list response format

Tags: netlink, proto

I'm working on the golang netlink ipset control library.

Everything is working fine except I have no idea how to parse the answer I'm getting from netlink for the list command.

The data I'm getting obviously is what I'm looking for.

But I'm not able to find a spec for the format!

Can anybody point me to the right doc?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a lib https://github.com/subgraph/go-nfnetlink, which contains a working parser.